# How upload captured image file to sever in java script HTML PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I working on a project where user capture photo from camera and show captured photo, but I want upload That Photo to server . How we can upload that image file to server. I am new please help me.
please help me how we upload image file to server. I tried much but can not upload successfully.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NigraniSof</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">

</head>

<body>

<button id="start-camera">Start Camera</button>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
<button id="click-photo">Click Photo</button>
<div id="dataurl-container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
    <div id="dataurl-header">Image Data URL</div>
    <textarea id="dataurl" readonly></textarea>
</div>

<script>

let camera_button = document.querySelector("#start-camera");
let video = document.querySelector("#video");
let click_button = document.querySelector("#click-photo");
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
let dataurl = document.querySelector("#dataurl");
let dataurl_container = document.querySelector("#dataurl-container");

camera_button.addEventListener('click', async function() {
    let stream = null;

    try {
        stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    }
    catch(error) {
        alert(error.message);
        return;
    }

    video.srcObject = stream;

    video.style.display = 'block';
    camera_button.style.display = 'none';
    click_button.style.display = 'block';
});

click_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    
    dataurl.value = image_data_url;
    dataurl_container.style.display = 'block';
});

</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the canvas to an img tag for capturing and then you can take the image value using file reader method of javascript ,from that u will get the file blob which u can pass to php function using Ajax call. After that u can access that file blob in php which u can save to your server as well.